# linux: how to troubleshoot forwarded port?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, port-forwarding

My home internet connection has a static IP address (eg: `123.123.123.123`)

I have configured my router to forward port `9000` to an internal host (`192.168.1.101`), which is running `Ubuntu 14-04`.

[image]

I run `netcat` listening on port 9000:

```
$ nc -l 9000
```

**Connecting from inside my LAN:**

On another machine on my LAN I can telnet to that port:

```
$ telnet 192.168.1.101 9000
Trying 192.168.1.101...
Connected to 192.168.1.101.
Escape character is '^]'.
hello world
```

and the connection succeeds

```
$ nc -l 9000
hello world
```

**Connecting from outside my LAN:**

However, if I try to connect via my external IP address I cannot get through:

```
$ telnet 123.213.123.123 9000
Trying 123.213.123.123...
```

**Firewall issue?**

I tried to allow port 9000 on iptables (I am **no** expert on `iptables` btw!):

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
```

This is my resulting configuration:

```
$ sudo iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 203 packets, 16977 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 178 packets, 23749 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

`telnet` still can't get through.

I think the `iptables` config might be unnecessary anyway though, because `ufw status` says it's inactive:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

**Port scanning says it's open:**

If I run a [port scanner](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) on my external IP with `nc -l 9000` running it says the port is open.

[image]

If I run `tcpdump` I can't see anything coming in on port 9000 when I try `telnet` to the port. However, running the port scanner does show up:

```
18:41:34.023692 IP 198.199.98.246.49977 > my_host.9000: Flags [S], seq 3955039481, win 14600, options [mss 1400,sackOK,TS val 4051434607 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
18:41:34.023748 IP my_host.9000 > 198.199.98.246.49977: Flags [S.], seq 3541700333, ack 3955039482, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 465840988 ecr 4051434607,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:41:34.250110 IP 198.199.98.246.49977 > my_host.9000: Flags [.], ack 1, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 4051434663 ecr 465840988], length 0
18:41:34.250973 IP 198.199.98.246.49977 > my_host.9000: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 4051434664 ecr 465840988], length 0
18:41:34.251035 IP my_host.9000 > 198.199.98.246.49977: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 2, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 465841045 ecr 4051434664], length 0
18:41:34.477197 IP 198.199.98.246.49977 > my_host.9000: Flags [.], ack 2, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 4051434720 ecr 465841045], length 0
```

**Questions:**

I'm at a bit of a loss as to where the problem is.

- **How can I diagnose where the issue is?**
- **How come the port scan data comes through, but not my telnet?**
- **How can I allow incoming connections?**

Answer (score 0):

You can diagnose the problem by plugging directly into the WAN port, and playing ISP to see what (exactly) is up. Requires some work, and static IP addressing, in all probability, but it will tell you if your ISP is messing with you.

Comment: Right, let's rethink this problem. List exactly which pieces of hardware are in play here, from the outside in (unless it's just your linux box doing everything). Mention any routers, switches, etc. Mention any ISP equipment. I need to form a mental picture.